# How to change to basic STM32CubdeIDE view

Tags: stm32cubeide

I want to change my editor and I made a big mistake. I installed Darkest Dark theme and after that, my whole STM32CUBeIDE changed, then I deleted it. So view is like eclipse view, but I want to go back to my basic view of STM32CUBEIDE. For example when I click build console doesn't show me anything. I don't even know if project is build or not. I don't want to configure debugger and other things again.

Answer (score 0):

reset the perspective it will be fixed